# Error: Could not find or load main class $(concat_lines Maven 3.3.9 in solaris

Tags: java, maven, solaris

I have installed maven 3.3.9 and have setup the M2_HOME and PATH and I have exported it in solaris. My java version in 1.7.

But when I start or do mvn -v I am getting error "Error: Could not find or load main class $(concat_lines". If I install maven 3.0.3 it is working fine.

Can anyone help me out resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1.Try `mvn clean install`. 3.0.3 and 3.3.9 have compatibility issue. Even i had to face a lot of trouble.

2.Can you check if the main class is specified in the configuration. [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751714/maven-jar-builder-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi, I am getting while installation itself. After setting up maven and maven home and to verify if it is correctly installed, I am doing mvn -version to check if  it is installed correctly or not. At that time I am getting "Error: Could not find or load main class $(concat_lines" this message.

Comment: if you have changed your java version you might face this issue

Comment: I am using java 1.7

Comment: Can you add the latest maven-compiler-plugin and try??

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the shell on Solaris, which is not POSIX-compliant. The `mvn` shell script in version 3.3.9 contains `$()` constructs that are not supported on Solaris 10 (see [MNG-5829](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5829)).

To solve this problem, you could either upgrade to Maven 3.5.0 or downgrade to Maven 3.2.5.

Comment: That is not correct. This is a bug in Solaris. The shell is not fully [POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03).