# Kotlin + Maven assembling: no main manifest attribute

Tags: maven, jar, kotlin

**I have problem assembling Kotlin project with some dependencies to JAR file using Maven.**

How am i assembling project to JAR:

```
RightPanel -> MavenProjects -> Lifecycle -> package -> run
```

When i running JAR file:

```
java -jar path.jar
```

I'm getting following error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in path.jar
```

I've added  `maven-assembly-plugin` like [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html):

**So my plugins directory looks like this:**

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals> <goal>single</goal> </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`main.class` property defined here:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <kotlin.version>1.1.51</kotlin.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <main.class>ru.icarumbas.main.HelloKt</main.class>
</properties>
```

**Some facts:**

- `Hello.kt` is starter class and it has fun `main(...){}`
- When i unarchive JAR it has META-INF folder.

**Versions:**

- Platform: Mac OS
- Kotlin version: 1.1.51
- Maven version: 4.0.0

Maybe i'm missing something. I've already looked on a lot of questions alike this, and they didn't help me. So please don't mark this as duplicate and write a comment if you want to see more code. I didn't show my full `pom.xml` file so write me if you want to see it full.

Comment: Hi @icarumbas, have you found a solution on this?

Comment: @KennethC yes, i use gradle

Comment: I see.. too bad my library only supports maven.. thanks for the reply!

Comment: @KennethC i'm not completely sure, but i think library doesn't know anything about what dependency build system you're using.

Comment: i think for selenium, they do.. 

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/selenium_installation/installing_selenium_libraries/

"Due to missing native language bindings for Kotlin, you have to use the Java Bindings, e.g. with maven Java"

Comment: @KennethC they're talking about java bindings compatible with Kotlin there, not about maven or gradle. I think you were confused by this line. Just try with gradle)

Comment: Woah. you're right, it worked with gradle. thanks sir!!

Answer (score 5):

I've got such problems with kotlin and maven.
I've solved it in following way (Application.kt):

```
package org.somepackage

open class Application {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            // something..
        }
    }
}
```

-- So first i've written the kotlin class with main inside it.

Secondly as in your case defined the main class in props in a following way `<main.class>org.somepackage.Application</main.class>`

After mvn clean install command finished i've got the necessary someapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar which was able to work.

And at the end please pay attention that you run exactly jar-with-dependencies.jar (not a stripped version like a app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar).

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have one of the plugins missing. add the bellow to pom.xml file

```
`<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>
                            yourclassnameKt
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>`
```

The plugin will add MANIFEST.mf file, which will tell the Java runtime which class to execute.

There is  another issue that has the same problem ->
[Maven Jar Builder: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751714/maven-jar-builder-could-not-find-or-load-main-class/49288721#49288721)

Reference: https://michaelrice.com/2016/08/hello-world-with-kotlin-and-maven/

Answer (score 0):

Your POM file is correct, no need to add anything. Just run the generated JAR postfixed with `*-jar-with-dependencies.jar` in target directory.