# java maven make jar : Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem with making executable jar from my project.
I've made a test project with the name

> test_project

there is 1 package

> testpack

and a public class with my main()

> testclass

```
     package testpack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

 public class testclass{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {...}
```

I have tried to plugins maven-jar-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin just to see what the difference; in both cases i have the same problem with

```
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>testpack.testclass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>testpack.testclass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class testpack.testclass

yes I have read this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean) and it didn't help me

I've checked my env variables and all the step 1 points; I think i just don't understand how to point on my main() in maven setup

I don't understand were can I find this [information about my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751714/maven-jar-builder-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

```
<archive>
    <manifest>
      <mainClass>com.domain.project.MainClass</mainClass>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
```

what's the right way to point on the main class?

Comment: What is your main class name, provide the complete class name along with package name.

Comment: @Sambit it looks like this :   package testpack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

 public class testclass{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {...}

Comment: First write simple Hello World in the main class and test.

Comment: is testClass in the same project than pom wich is configured the plugin? is testClas located in src/main/java/testPack folder?

Comment: @Sambit that's the problem - this is my hello world with maven and attempt to build this project into jar; even if i make a new project with just 1 class and system out "hi" i still have the same problem with java couldn't find the main class

Comment: Ok, let me look into it.

Comment: @imperezivan yes it is and pom.xml is in the root folder

Comment: I have provided the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below the maven jar plugin usage. I have written a simple Hello World Program just to demonstrate.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.ddlab.rnd.App
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If you want to check the complete small source code, check this github link. 
https://github.com/debjava/runnableJar

I did not add any classpath dependencies, if you want, you can add other libraries like this.

```
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
<classpathPrefix>you lib dir containing all jar file/</classpathPrefix>
```

Comment: thanks, i cloned it and still get the same error; so i thinks it means that i'm still missing something on my windows setup ...

Comment: Did you clone the project ? Did you run the command mvn clean package ?